# can we use machine learning concepts to extract blood vessel from retinal image?

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I am working on blood vessel extraction, i want to know whether we can extract blood vessel using machine learning algorithm? which algorithm i can use to yield good results?

Comment: [What have you found](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=blood+vessel+extraction+machine+learning) so far?

Comment: sir i have processed it this way rgb image--> green channel of image--->gabor filter this is what i have done till now

Comment: This is a homework? A research theme? The question is a little bit fishy because one usually tackle "extract X from image Y" with image processing methods first. Google "vesselness" and check the results for reliable image processing techniques.

Comment: its my projct work sir..i am new to the concepts of machine learning